# How to add a linebreak before any character in a set of characters in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

Is there a way to add a linebreak before any character in a set of characters in Notepad++?

E.g. I would like to add a linebreak before any number.

Before:

```
1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 2 sed do eiusmod 
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 3 Ut enim ad minim 
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 4 nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
commodo consequat.
```

After:

```
1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
2 sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
3 Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
4 nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
```

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- replace what:  `(\d+)`
- replace to:  `\n$1`
- make sure "regular expression" is checked